# Problem with WCF BasicHttpBinding

Tags: php, .net, wcf, web-services

I created a WCF service, I have two endpoints one for wsHttpBinding and one for basicHttpBinding.
I am able to consume the wsHttpBinding and basicHttpBinding, just fine with ASP.Net call.

I am having problems trying to consume the basicHttpBinding service with php.

Here is the metadata.

```
    <wsdl:definitions name="PURLService" targetNamespace="http://xxx.xxx.com/TMServices/">
  <wsdl:import namespace="http://tempuri.org/" location="http://xxx.xxx.com/TMServices/PURLServ.svc?wsdl=wsdl1"/>
  <wsdl:types/>
  <wsdl:service name="PURLService">
    <wsdl:port name="WSHttpBinding_ITMService" binding="i0:WSHttpBinding_ITMService">
      <soap12:address location="http://xxx.xxx.com/TMServices/PURLServ.svc/ws"/>
      <wsa10:EndpointReference>
        <wsa10:Address>http://xxx.xxx.com/TMServices/PURLServ.svc/ws</wsa10:Address>
        <Identity>
          <Spn>host/xxx.xxx.com</Spn>
        </Identity>
      </wsa10:EndpointReference>
    </wsdl:port>
    <wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_ITMService" binding="i0:BasicHttpBinding_ITMService">
      <soap:address location="http://xxx.xxx.com/TMServices/PURLServ.svc/basic"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

when I try to call the basicHttpBinding endpoint by giving the address http://xxx.xxx.com/TMServices/PURLServ.svc/basic on php I get the following error "SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://xxx.xxx.com/TMServices/PURLServ.svc/basic' : failed to load external entity "

this is the php code:

```
$wsdl = "http://xxx.xxx.com/TMServices/PURLServ.svc/basic";

try {


$client = new SoapClient($wsdl);


$result = $client->TestServices(); //this should return true if accessed

print $result;
} catch (Exception $e) {
echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}   

?>
```

Also I am not able to access http://xxx.xxx.com/TMServices/PURLServ.svc/basic directly I get a 400 Bad Request error.

when I try with http://xxx.xxx.com/TMServices/PURLServ.svc?wsdl address on the php code I get the following error: "Cannot process the message because the content type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8'. "

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you access http://xxx.xxx.com/TMServices/PURLServ.svc directly?  (without adding the /basic)

Comment: @Tim yes I can. It shows the default page and gives me the link to see to http://xxx.xxx.com/TMServices/PURLServ.svc?wsdl which also works

Comment: For the .. 'text/xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8' error. You must defined SOAP_1_2 in your SoapClient. This will change  'text/xml' to 'application/soap+xml' in the header

=>   $client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array('soap_version' => SOAP_1_2));

Answer (score 0):

Try going directly to the service (`http://xxx.xxx.com/TMServices/PURLServ.svc`) page.  Chances are there is an issue in your service that is preventing it from loading, and you should get an idea what it is when you try to browse to it.

My memory is hazy, but I seem to recall seeing similar behavior in the past ("Cannot process the message because the content type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8'.") when I had a problem with the service not loading.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure your WCF service and PHP client are using the same version of the SOAP protocol (1.1) over basicHttpBinding.

Create your PHP client by referencing the WSDL file.

For example:

```
// Create a new soap client based on the service's metadata (WSDL)
$client = new SoapClient("http://localhost:8731/FileUploadService?wsdl")
```

As far as the character set fault (UTF-8) you can instruct your PHP client which character set it should use:

```
$client->soap_defencoding = 'UTF-8';
```